# FFmpeg Flags for generating fixed amount of images related to video length

Tags: video, ffmpeg, png

I am using this command :

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -vf fps=1/60 -s 274x175  thumb%d.png
```

to extract 1 frame from video for every minute of it. 
What i want to learn how to do is :
Extract a total of 10 images from video regardless of its length that are relative to distance of video.

Example :

1.If video length is 15 minutes (900 seconds) it will extract one image from every 90 seconds of video.
2.If video length is 22 minutes (1320 seconds) it will extract one image from every 132 seconds of video.

And one more thing , is it possible to use ffmpeg to set output quality of those images or limit maximum size(as in file size , **not** dimensions) for each image that is going to get outputted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to script this.

## The quick & easy way

Would be to get the duration from `ffprobe`:

```
$ ffprobe -v error -select_streams 0:v -show_entries format=duration -of default=nw=1 input.mkv 
duration=600.032000
```

However, this may not be accurate.

## Duration can be "fragile"

If your input is damaged or mangled it can return an incorrect duration. (You can test this with some formats by truncating it with `dd`.) If you are confident that your inputs are fine, then `ffprobe` can be a quick and easy method.

## A slower, but more bulletproof method

If you find issues with `ffprobe` returning incorrect values then you'll have to fully decode the file:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input -f null -
```

Parse the second to last line of the console output and you will see the real duration listed something like:

```
time=00:04:44.95
```

This can be almost instant or take many seconds. How long this takes will depend on your input duration, input complexity, and your hardware.

## Image quality

You asked:

> is it possible to use ffmpeg to set output quality of those images

#### PNG

No, since it is lossless. You can control the amount of compression with the `-compression_level` option, but `ffmpeg` already uses the highest compression by default.

#### JPG

Yes, either with `-q:v` or `-b:v`. For `-q:v` a sane range to test is between 2-8: the higher the value, the lower the quality and the smaller the file size.

Answer (score 0):

there's no real way to do that since FFmpeg doesn't really "know" exactly how long each stream is.  However if you run ffmpeg -i `input` beforehand, you can use that to "guess" how long the stream is (based on what the container is) and use that, I suppose.